# When a binary relation is connected?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, definition, examples-counterexamples, relations

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_relation) wiki article is claimed that a binary relation $\mathcal R$ on a set $X$ is connected (by definition) if the proposition
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}(\forall a)(\forall b)\big((a\in X)\wedge(b\in X)\wedge(a\neq b)\rightarrow(a\mathcal R b)\vee(b\mathcal Ra)\big)
$$
is true and then it is there observed that $\mathcal R$ is connected iff the proposition
$$
\tag{2}\label{2}(\forall a)(\forall b)\big((a\in X)\wedge(b\in X)\rightarrow(a\mathcal R b)\vee(a=b)\vee(b\mathcal R a)\big)
$$
is true.

So, I would like to understand if a connected relation $\mathcal R$ must be reflexive or not since the proposition \eqref{2} confused me a lot: indeed, it seems to me that it implicitly ensures that any $x$ in $X$ is related with it self by $\mathcal R$ so that we could say that $\mathcal R$ is connected **if and only if** the proposition
$$
\tag{3}\label{3}(\forall a)(\forall b)\big((a\in X)\wedge(b\in X)\rightarrow a\mathcal R b\big)
$$
is true but I am not really sure about so that I thought to put a question where I ask for elucidation, asking in particular if \eqref{3} is equivalent to \eqref{1} and so if a connected relation must be reflexive. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: What explorations have you done to try to construct counterexamples? For instance, have you explored the relations on the set $X = \{a,b\}$?

Comment: Okay, I perhaps understood: the relation $\{(a,b)\}$ is connected but not reflexive, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference article is saying that a relation is connected iff

$\forall a(\forall b(((a\in X\land b\in X)\rightarrow(a\neq b\rightarrow(aRb\ \vee\ bRA))))$, or equivalently as:

$(A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\leftrightarrow(A\land B\rightarrow C)$,

$\forall a(\forall b((a\in X\land b\in X\land a\neq b)\rightarrow(aRb\ \vee\ bRA)))$, your (1).

And conditional disjunction tells us that $(a\neq b\rightarrow(aRb\ \vee\ bRA))$ is equivalent to $(a=b\vee(aRb\ \vee\ bRA))$  and so as the article states, the definition of connected is therefore also equivalent to:

$\forall a(\forall b((a\in X\land b\in X)\rightarrow(a= b \vee (aRb\ \vee\ bRA))))$, your (2).

That is your (1) and (2) are equivalent.
And under this definition, we cannot conclude that $R$ is reflexive. That is, if a relation is connected, then it is not necessarily reflexive.

But the article introduces another term, which is strongly connected. A relation is strongly connected iff

$\forall a(\forall b((a\in X\land b\in X)\rightarrow(aRb\ \vee\ bRA)))$, your (3).

And from this definition it is clear that if a relation is strongly connected it is reflexive. Your (3) is not equivalent to (1).

Comment: A strongly connected relation cannot be reflexive since it is asymmetric as stated into the article: the proposition $(3)$ into the question (which I got wrong) is not that of strogly connected reletion since a relation $\mathcal R$ is strongly connected if for any $x$ and $y$ must be $x\mathcal Ry$ or $y\mathcal Rx$ and if one holds then the other cannot hold. Do I am wrong?

Comment: Suppose $R$ is connected and is on $X$. Suppose $x\in X$. Then $x \in X$ and $x \in X$ and so by definition $(xRx$ or $xRx)$ and so $xRx$. Hence $R$ is reflexive. The article states that if $R$ is connected then $\overline{R}$ is asymmetric (not $R$). Further down in the article it states: “A relation is strongly connected if, and only if, it is connected and reflexive”. If we state $A$ or $B$ in logic, $A$ can be true, $B$ can be true, or both $A$ and $B$ can be true.

Comment: Oops, meant to say suppose $R$ is strongly connected… (whenever I said $R$ is connected.. ).

Comment: I did not see the overline over $R$ so that you are right: forgive for my oversight. So I just approved and upvoted your answer: thanks really for it! :-)